# How to get a bare, recursive directory listing in Linux, excluding some directories

Tags: linux, bash

I need to obtain a recursive directory listing in Linux with only the directory and file name. It needs to include all files including hidden files with the exception of files name “.svn”.

I have tried multiple combinations of the “ls” command and haven’t been able to figure it out. When using “ls –R direname/ grep –v /$” I get a directory heading followed by a colon, which I cannot use.

If I have a directory name test with files and a sub-directory named test2 with files, I need the output to look like the following:

```
test
test/.filehidden1
test/file2
test/file3.txt
test/test2.log
test/test2/file.hidden1
test/test2/file2.boo
test/test2/file3.boo2
```

Notice there is no leading forward slash

Comment: I bet you could do that with the "find" command.

Comment: `tree`? This is available only on certain distributions, though. Others may have them via installable packages

Comment: Since this is talking about svn, how about `svn ls -R`? http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.list.html

Comment: Is this an XYQuestion better answered with "svn export"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find . -name .svn -prune -o -print
```

`-prune` tells it to not descend into any matching directories.

Answer (score 1):

This should do:

```
find . ! -path \*.svn\*
```

This tells find to recursively list all files from `.` whose *pathname* does not contains `.svn`. This is not perfect since it may hide for instance file `foo.svnbar`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
find DIRNAME ! -name .svn
```

Comment: I'm sorry but this won't work as `-name` will list files contained in the `.svn` directory.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to obtain a recursive directory listing in Linux with only the directory and file name. It needs to include all files including hidden files with the exception of files name “.svn”.

Do you want to get a list of files in a Subversion repository?
This will do just that:

```
svn ls -R
```

If not, then you can use `find`:

```
find . ! -path '*/.svn/*' ! -name .svn
```

You mentioned "Notice there is no leading forward slash".
If that's very important, then the `find` command can be rephrased as:

```
find * .[^.]* ! -path '.svn/*' ! -name .svn
```